# Using PV to Count lines and show total lines rather then total bytes in the pipe

Tags: linux, bash, unix, pipe

I am trying to make a little script that shows me total storage used on disk by a directory. To figure it out I am using the du command. However, in order to give some feedback to the user while DU works away on a really large directory, I would like to run the output through a pipe and show the line count, so the user can also get an idea about how many folders and files there are in the directory. Here is my code:

```
du -ah | pv -l | tail -n 1 | sed 's/\.$//'
```

However, though the pv commands uses lines, it still shows total data through the pipe in Kilobytes rather then lines. Is there a way to show it total number of lines piped through, rather then bytes. Maybe a different command?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain your requirement with some sample example? I am not able to understand.

Comment: Please present some sample output, for me it provides lines, time and rate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`du` comes with the `-s` flag to only display the total, so just do e.g. this instead:

```
$ du -sh /tmp | cut -f1
4.9M
```

Regarding `pv`:

> However, though the pv commands uses lines, it still shows total data through the pipe in Kilobytes rather then lines.

Are you sure?

```
$ find /tmp/ | pv >/dev/null
44.6kiB 0:00:00 [3.19MiB/s] [   <=>  
^^^^^^^

$ find /tmp/ | pv -l >/dev/null
1.24k 0:00:00 [86.5k/s] [   <=>  
^^^^^

$ find /tmp/ | wc -l
1237
^^^^
```

Looks like lines to me (as in, it's working as expected)?

Comment: Wow, silly me, thank you! It would always show me the number as N.Nk and I totally wrongly assumed that k meant Kilobits, not thousands.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to monitor MP3 conversion of a bulk of files. This helped me, hope helps researchers on this issue:

```bash
$ find . -type f | grep "wav$" | 
  while read f; do
  ffmpeg -loglevel panic -n -i "$f" -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 1 "${f%.wav}.mp3";
  echo "OK."; 
  done | 
  pv -l -s `find . -type f | grep "wav$" | wc -l` > /dev/null
```

It is a one-liner.

<sub>Also archiving for myself</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a=`find . -iname -prune -o -type f -print` 
c=`printf "%b\n" "$a" | du -ah`
echo "Displaying all the files on your machine with respect to their size********************************************"
printf "%b\n" "$c" | sed '$d'
echo "Finished displaying********************************************"
echo ""
b=`find . -iname -prune -o -type f -print | du -ah | wc -l`
echo "Total number of files exist on your machine is:" $b
totalSize=`printf "%b\n" "$c" | tail -1`
echo ""
echo "Total number of space occupied on disk in KB" $totalSize
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use wc (word count) command to fetch the line count

usage:

ls | wc -l